# React Redux apply filters to backed call and to route

Tags: reactjs, routes, redux

My application is using React and Redux.

I have two components on the page which are filters such as status or region, which when clicked should hit a backend url like 'https://somebackend.com?status=published&region=northamerica'.  Then my index component should display the new list.  If status filter is changed to ‘draft', we would of course hit:  'https://somebackend.com?status=draft&region=northamerica' and re render the index list.

I have not worked with routing before this application, and I don’t
   really know how to order these events in React-Redux.  Here is my
   current idea, but is has problems.  Other solutions much appreciated:

1)in the StatusFilter component, call an updateStatusFilter action, when a filter is clicked create an action that has type:statusFilter, payload:”published”

2)in my reducer, update the property of state called statusFilter to “published”

3)now, back in my StatusFilter component, in mapStateToProps, I capture the fact that state has changed, So I want to call the route in my app such as https://example.com/publications?status=draft&region=northamerica, so I get those values from the state, and manually call the route from the mapStatesToProps function

4)the route is set to "component={PublicationsIndex}/> 
5)in PublicationIndex,componentWillMount, we get the params from the state, and put together the url with which to hit the backend, ok I’ll stop here...

This is all kinds of convoluted.  Sorry, any help to get me thinking along the right lines, appreciated.  I feel like I'm fighting figuring out what drives this, the route, or the state change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use React router's `Link` to handle this.

```
<Link to={{pathname:`${path}/&status=published`} > Published </Link>
```

Comment: but there is another filter called region, what does the route look like, and what does that link look like: <Link to={{pathname:`${path}/&region=northamerica`} > Published </Link>?  Where do I put together all the query params for the backend?

Comment: Can you share a screen shot of how your filters look? Would help in understanding the filters better